# Unexpected Error: Error renaming temporary file, Text File Busy

Tags: hadoop

I've been working on a **Ubuntu** and **Hadoop**, I'm at installing and configuring stage.
For this I'm following a link:
[Hadoop Beginner](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1167462/Hadoop-Beginners-Guide-How-To-Install)

When I am configuring the Hadoop so when I reach to

```
gedit core-site.xml
```

I do the editing and when I save it so it gives an error:

[image]

I searched couples of links but could not get the answer that how to overcome this problem.

Every file when I edit and save to same error shows.

Answer (score 0):

Check if some `java` processes are running:

```
# ps -A | grep java
```

If it's so, check if it's the `NameNode` or `DataNode` service:

```
# jps
16192 Jps
1 DataNode
```

In this case, just stop the process by ID and try to edit configuration again.